# How to add external accessible folder(s) to webpack dev server

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am starting to use webpack (vue-cli webpack installation), and in my project I have 2 folders (pdfview and imgview).

My webpack configuration is the default in vue-cli template, I has not modified yet (just added some loaders for sass and fonts).

This two folders are document viewers (one to PDF and another to image files), and they work in that way:

[domain]/pdfview/viewer.html?file=[path to file]

When I run "npm run dev", webpack dev server start as http://localhost:8080, but it's in memory and my app have an iframe trying to load the viewers.

How can I expose this folders paths into webpack dev server so they are accessible in "localhost:8080/pdfview/viewer.html?file=[path to file]" ?

I have not found any content about that, if someone have an article, or know some section on documentation that I has not saw yet, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

PS: The two viewers have the same folder structure: viewer.js, viewer.html and viewer.css.

Other PS: Sorry for my bad english...